# Javascript if statement in RPG

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm learning about canvas by making a simple RPG.

I'm trying to make it so that if you walk into a certain area, it runs a function. So I used an `if`:

```
if (x<150, x>50, y<150, y>50) {
(code I want to execute)
}
```

But even when the statement is false, it's still considered true. I want it so that all statements in the parentheses must be true for the code to execute. Any help?

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&&`:

```
if (x < 150  && x > 50 && y < 150 && y > 50) {
   // (code I want to execute)
}
```

Or to separate each part for readability:

```
if ((x < 150)  && (x > 50) && (y < 150) && (y > 50)) {
   // (code I want to execute)
}
```

---

*To learn more, check out:*

- [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&`, not `,`:

```
if (x<150 && x>50 && y<150 && y>50) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Using && means you want all of the conditions between the brackets evaluated. The code below will be executed if x is less the 150 AND y is less than 150 AND x is greater than 50 AND y is greater than 50. If only 3 of the conditions are satisfied, the code will not run. As a result your new code will look like this:

```
if (x < 150  && x > 50 && y < 150 && y > 50) {
    // (code I want to execute)
}
```

Using || basically means or, and the code gets executed if any of the conditions are valid. The code below will be executed if x is less the 150 OR y is less than 150 OR x is greater than 50 OR y is greater than 50. In effect, if even 1 of the conditions is met the code will run.

```
if (x < 150  || x > 50 || y < 150 || y > 50) {
    // (code I want to execute)
}
```

You can find a simple tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)